# SQL Counting Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've the following set of data

```
id      name         in            out
---------------------------------------
1      jhon          True         False
1      jhon          True         False
1      jhon          True         True
1      jhon          True         True
2      Smith         True         True
3      Test          True        False
```

I want to get the count result as

```
jhon = 2
smith = 1
Test = 0
```

I need to count only the rows that contain true in both (in, out)

how I can accomplish this? I'm still newbie and it only works for me to count all the rows in standards sql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple `group by`:

```
select name, count(*)
from the_table
where in = 'True' 
  and out = 'True'
group by name;
```

---

You might need to properly quote the keywords `in` and `out` (e.g `"in"` and `"out"`), not sure if they are reserved keywords in SQL Server.

---

**Edit** after the question was changed

You can get a zero count by doing a filtered aggregate:

```
select name, 
       count(case when in = 'True' and out = 'True' then 1 else null end) as true_count
from the_table
group by name;
```

The above works because aggregate functions (`count()`, `sum()`, ...) ignore null values. The result of the `case` expression is `null` if at least one of the columns is not `True`.

Comment: thank you,,, it was very simple but I didn't thought it would be like this :)

Comment: I've edited my question... what if I want to show also who has 0?

Comment: @KhalilRumman: see my edit, but it's not considered polite to change the question once you have an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have group your records by name with where condition.

```
select name, count(id)
 from table_name
where in = 'True' 
 and out = 'True'
group by name;
```

Comment: I've edited my question... what if I want to show also who has 0?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean just this:

```
SELECT name, Count(*) as 'total_count'  FROM test WHERE in = 'true' and out = 'true' group by name
```

If so, then yup that works!

Comment: The backticks are invalid in SQL Server

Comment: I've edited my question... what if I want to show also who has 0?

Answer (score 0):

Use Below query.

```
select distinct name , isnull(qry.totalcount,0) from table_name left   join 
(
select name, count(id) as totalcount
from table_name
where in = 'True' 
and out = 'True'
group by name) qry 
on (qry.name = table_name.name)
```